# Find parameter and compare the date from other table, sort by parameter

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table of employees (ID) and table when it changes their status (date, status, ID(FK)).  I need to display list of employees sorted according to the status of a specified date

```
employees  
ID, Name   
1, Jack  
2, Ralf  
3, Jenny  

changes
IDchange, Date, Status, ID
1, 2015-01-01, 2, 1       //Jack started in 2015-1-1 with status 2
2, 2015-03-01, 1, 2       //Ralf started in 2015-3-1 with status 1
3, 2015-04-01, 1, 3       //Jenny started in 2015-4-1 with status 1
4, 2015-08-01, 2, 2       //Ralf change status to 2 in 2015-8-1 
5, 2015-10-01, 3, 2       //Ralf change status to 3 in 2015-10-1
6, 2016-04-01, 4, 1       //Jack change status to 4 in 2016-04-1
```

I tried theese for any date $My_Date, but I don't know how to repair it for all changes, it check only last date change

```
<?php
$sql2="SELECT *, Status
     FROM employees s
     JOIN (
          SELECT  MAX(Date) max_date, ID, Status
            FROM  changes sml
           WHERE  date <= '".$My_Date."'
        GROUP BY  ID
      ) sml ON (sml.ID = s.ID)
 ORDER BY Status, Name ASC";

 $result2 = MySQL_Query($sql2);
 ... ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a correlated subquery in order to get the `status` per `ID` of each employee:

```sql
SELECT ID, Name, (SELECT Status
                  FROM changes AS c
                  WHERE e.ID = c.ID AND date <= ?
                  ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1) AS Status
FROM employees AS e
ORDER BY Status, Name ASC
```

The subquery will return the status for the *current* employee that is *closer to* the parameterised date value.

Comment: Thank you, it is OK, small question: how I easy get Date of change?

Comment: @DaveMX What do you mean by *Date of change*?

Comment: Yes Date of change please

Answer (score 0):

We can do it using a simple join query. As we are passing the `date` as parameter, there is no need to calculate `max(date)`, example below:

```
select e.name, s.date, s.status
from employee e join status s on e.id = s.id
where s.date = ?
order by s.status desc
```